# Rewrite Static Files in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am in the following situation: I have some static images in the following format:

**cdn-x.domain.com/dirname/image.jpg**

cdn-x is a variable subdomain (cdn-y, cdn-z etc) and is defined as a Server Alias, therefore all the various cdns point to the same path on the server.

The path structure is as follows:

```
- cdn
  - x
    - dirname1
    - dirname2
  - y
    - dirname1
    - dirname2
  - z
    - dirname1
    - dirname2
  - etc
- httpdocs
     - .htaccess
     - php script
```

I would like to find the right condition for Apache to check for **the existence of the file in the right CDN**, and **ONLY if not**, call the php.

Initially each cdn was a virtual host in itself (not an alias server), and therefore it was very simple to obtain the existence or otherwise of the file as the path was direct

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\/0-9-a-z_.]+)$ notfound.php?val=$1 [L]
```

Working with alias servers is much more convenient, but I can't point apache to the right path of static files. Can someone help me?

Comment: How nany `cdn` subdomains do you have?

Comment: So your `domain.com` document root is set to `httpdocs` here, yes? And that of the CDN domains to the `cdn` folder outside of that? Then the request for `cdn-x.domain.com/dirname/image.jpg` would not "land" in your `httpdocs/.htaccess` to begin with, you'd need a .htaccess inside `cdn` then.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by below .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Check for existence of file in CDN x, dirname1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-x.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/x/dirname1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-x.domain.com/dirname1/$1 [L]

# Check for existence of file in CDN x, dirname2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-x.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/x/dirname2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-x.domain.com/dirname2/$1 [L]

# Check for existence of file in CDN y, dirname1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-y.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/y/dirname1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-y.domain.com/dirname1/$1 [L]

# Check for existence of file in CDN y, dirname2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-y.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/y/dirname2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-y.domain.com/dirname2/$1 [L]

# Check for existence of file in CDN z, dirname1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-z.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/z/dirname1%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-z.domain.com/dirname1/$1 [L]

# Check for existence of file in CDN z, dirname2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn-z.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cdn/z/dirname2%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn-z.domain.com/dirname2/$1 [L]

# If the file doesn't exist in any CDN, pass the request to a PHP script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ notfound.php?val=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work :(